# Java - Оптимизация кода

Tags: java, android

Можно как-то оптимизировать, метод изложенный ниже.У меня создаются картинки различного цвета с помощью генератора случайных чисел, всё работает хорошо, но вот кода слишком много получается..

```
private void pickColor() {
    switch (rand.nextInt(12)) {
        case 0:
            colorBall = R.drawable.red;
        case 1:
            colorBall = R.drawable.blue;
        case 2:
            colorBall = R.drawable.night_blue;
        case 3:
            colorBall = R.drawable.green;
        case 4:
            colorBall = R.drawable.acqamarin;
        case 5:
            colorBall = R.drawable.night_acqamarin;
        case 6:
            colorBall = R.drawable.grey;
        case 7:
            colorBall = R.drawable.orange;
        case 8:
            colorBall = R.drawable.pink;
        case 9:
            colorBall = R.drawable.tomato;
        case 10:
            colorBall = R.drawable.violet;
        case 11:
            colorBall = R.drawable.yellow;
        default:
            colorBall = R.drawable.blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: а какой тип у colorBall?

Comment: заведите массив на 12 элементов и инициализируйте их нужными цветами (это одна строка). И выборка будет также одной строкой

Comment: можно enum написать, он тоже позволяет доступ по индексу и не требует инстанциирования класса

Answer (score 2):

Можно поместить все в массив и обращаться по индексу

```
Image colorBalls[] = new Image {
    R.drawable.red,
    R.drawable.blue,
    R.drawable.night_blue,
    R.drawable.green,
    R.drawable.acqamarin,
    R.drawable.night_acqamarin,
    R.drawable.grey,
    R.drawable.orange,
    R.drawable.pink,
    R.drawable.tomato,
    R.drawable.violet,
    R.drawable.yellow,
    R.drawable.blue
};

colorBall = colorBalls[rand.nextInt(12)];
```